# Angular Loading Error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I created a component loading and an interceptor for all requests in my application, loading appears on the screen until the request is finalized. However, I get an error whenever the component of my router outlet changes. can you help me?

My error:

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'true'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?

My code:

```
export class MasterPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementService, private loader: LoaderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  isLoading: Subject<boolean> = this.loader.isLoading;
}
```

Master-Page.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper default-theme" [ngClass]="getClasses()">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <main>
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <div class="pages container-fluid pt-4 pb-4 pl-4 pr-4 ">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" (click)="toggleSidebar()"></div>
  </main>
</div>
<app-loading *ngIf="isLoading | async"></app-loading>
```

My LoaderService:

```
export class LoaderService {
    isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
    show() {
        this.isLoading.next(true);
    }
    hide() {
        this.isLoading.next(false);
    }
}
```

My loader interceptor:

```
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor  {

  constructor(private loader: LoaderService) {

  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    this.loader.show()
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loader.hide())
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, it's an annoying warning that disappears after you compile your app in `--prod` mode.

To silence it :

```
constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewChecked(){
   this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```